# How to get AngularJS to fill initial tag value in svg template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I'm trying to get an AngularJS directive to set various properties in an svg tag.

```js
angular.module("complexNumbers")
.directive("cartesianPlane", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: { },
    templateUrl: "shared/cartesianPlane/cartesianPlaneView.html",
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.viewBox = {
        x : -20,
        y : -20,
        width : 40,
        height : 40,

        value : function() {
            return this.x + ' ' + this.y + ' ' + this.width + ' ' + this.height;
        }
      };
    },
    link: function($scope, $elem) {
      // Then adjust for aspect ratio
      var aspectRatio = $elem.height() / elem.width();
      $scope.viewBox.height = $scope.viewBox.width * aspectRatio;  
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<!-- cartesianPlaneView.html -->

<svg width='100%' height='100%' viewBox='{{viewBox.value()}}' style='position:relative; top:0px; left:0px; float:left;'>
<line class='axis' x1='{{viewBox.x}}' y1='0'  x2='{{viewBox.x + viewBox.width}}' y2='0'></line>
<line class='axis' x1='0' y1='{{viewBox.y}}' x2='0' y2='{{viewBox.y + viewBox.height}}'></line>
```

There are two problems with this method:

1) AngularJS seems to render the  tag from the templateUrl without inserting the values initially. Therefore the browser complains:

```
Error: Invalid value for <svg> attribute viewBox="{{viewBox.value()}}"
Error: Invalid value for <line> attribute y1="{{viewBox.y}}"
Error: Invalid value for <line> attribute y2="{{viewBox.y + viewBox.height}}"
Error: Invalid value for <line> attribute x1="{{viewBox.x}}"
Error: Invalid value for <line> attribute x2="{{viewBox.x + viewBox.width}}"
```

I would have thought that when the template was rendered, the initial values from $scope would be inserted immediately? Instead the template {{}} tags are going in as is.

2) The $elem parameter to the link function doesn't have width() and height() properties. When are these available and how can I compute & set the aspectRatio when they are?

```
Error: TypeError: $elem.height() is not a function
```

Comment: for 2) you can use`element.prop('offsetHeight');`

Comment: and that is your complete code ? I get the error you state but the interpolations are not compiled because the example does not have angular js file included. Do you have the same error with it included ?

Comment: No it isn't the complete code, the code snippet is not runnable.

Comment: $elem.prop('offsetHeight') and $elem.prop('offsetWidth') return 0 at the time of linking. Is there a later time they should be checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe for problem #1 you'll want to use `ng-attr`. So, in your directive, you'll use `ng-attr-viewBox`, `ng-attr-x`, etc...

As for your second problem, `.height()` should be available there and should be provided by JQLite

Comment: This answer gave a valid and recommended solution to (1), with the caveat that to preserve the camelCase the attribute needs to be ng-attr-view_box (note underscore). However .height() is not available in jqLite.

Comment: I am using angular 1.2 and chrome 56.  The only solution that worked for me is `<svg ng-attr-viewbox="{{myview}}" viewbox="0 0 100 100" >`  The second `viewbox` is a dummy to get past the initial load scope.

Answer (score 0):

Answert to point 2  You dont have loaded jQuery, height() is not available in jqLite https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angular-s-jqlite

1.) Create custom svg directive for example example-svg so browser will not interpret is as SVG

2.) Build svg element manually in link method and replace it in dom so when browser detects SVG element it will have proper attribute values.

```
 app.directive('exampleSvg' , function() {
 return {
   scope : {
    viewBox : '='
   },
   restrict : 'E',
   link : function(scope,element) {
    element.replaceWith('<svg viewBox="' + scope.viewBox + '"></svg>');
    $compile(element)(scope);
 }
});
```

Template

```
<example-svg viewBox="viewBox.value()"></example-svg>
```

On initial load scope is not replaced, it is replace on next digest so for   1 $digest of angular browser will not see interpolated scope, you are seeing it inside chrome inspector because you are seeing DOM after digest so interpolation is done.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying re. jqLite. A simper solution given by Hacknightly for the attribute issue is to add ng-attr-view_box, ng-attr-x1 etc.

Answer (score 0):

about the problem

```
Error: Invalid value for <line> attribute x1="{{viewBox.x1}}"
Error: Invalid value for <line> attribute y1="{{viewBox.y1}}"
```

you can replace the x1 and y1 by `ng-attr-x1` & `ng-attr-y1`

for more information read [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation)

*When using **`ngAttr`**, the allOrNothing flag of $interpolate  is used, so if any expression in the interpolated string results in undefined, the attribute is removed and not added to the element*